# Different group sizes for geom_jitter() and stat_summery()

Tags: r, ggplot2, figure

This is my first post. Please let me know if you need additional information to answer this question!

I have been trying to find out how to set different sizes for groups in geom_jitter() and stat_summery().

[figure made with the R script below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMkTk.png)

In this figure, 4 shapes are set for the 4 groups and I want to use the same shapes for the individual plot (using geom_jitter()) and the mean values of each group (using stat_summery()). I specify the sizes of the each shape as well because these shapes look slightly different in size if I use the same size for all of them. It turns out that geom_jitter() and stat_summery() use different definitions of size, so I need to use different values for "size" in geom_jitter() and stat_summery(). However, I cannot use scale_size_manual() for both of them, so I need to use a common size for either geom_jitter() or stat_summery(). This figure uses a common size for the mean values, but you see that the diamond for Group=1000 look smaller than the other three means.
Here is my R script for this figure.

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time,y=value),group=Group)+
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Group,shape = Group,size = Group), 
              position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0.2,dodge.width=0.6),alpha=0.3 ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values =  c(15,16,17,18))+
  scale_size_manual(values =  c(6,7,5,7))+
  scale_color_manual(values =  c("green","orange", "red", "blue"))+
  stat_summary(aes(group = Group,shape= Group),
               size=1.3, 
               fun.data="mean_cl_normal",  
               geom = "pointrange",  position = position_dodge(0.6)  )+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("90","150"))+ 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,10))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="lab value",x="lab time", fill="lab group")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,colour = "black"),axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,colour = "black"),axis.title=element_text(size=14,colour = "black"))
```

I will be very grateful if anyone could tell me how to set different sizes for those 4 shapes of the mean values.
I would also appreciate if anyone could tell me how to change the title of the legend (labs(fill="") doesn't work for some reason).

Comment: You are specifying color, which is different than fill, so I expect you want `color = "lab group"`

Comment: Thanks, Jon! When I changed fill="lab group" to color="lab group", it gives me two legends.. One has "Group" legend with different sizes and the other has "lab group" with different colors though the dots in the legend are very small..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you are using the `color` aes, hence you have to set the legend title via `color=` not `fill=`. Additionally you have to use the same title for all legends, i.e. do `labs(..., color="lab group", shape ="lab group", size="lab group")`. Otherwise the legends will not get merged. Second, to get the same sizes for the `geom_pointrange` map on the `size` aes too and set `fatten=1`. Finally I have set `show.legend=FALSE` to not display the point range in the legend.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

x <- data.frame(
  Time = factor(c(90, 150)),
  value = runif(100, 0, 10),
  Group = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(x, aes(x = Time, y = value)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Group, shape = Group, size = Group),
    position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.2, dodge.width = 0.6), 
    alpha = 0.3
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 17, 18)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(6, 7, 5, 7)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "orange", "red", "blue")) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = Group, shape = Group, size = Group),
    fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
    fatten = 1,
    geom = "pointrange", position = position_dodge(0.6),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("90", "150")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 10)) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = "lab value", x = "lab time", 
       color = "lab group", shape = "lab group", size = "lab group") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, stefan! It worked very well!! I really appreciate your help.
If you (or anyone else) can tell me how to make the color of the legend not transparent, I'd appreciate it as well.

Comment: Sure. This could be achieved via the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend`, i.e. do `+ guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))` to set the opacity for the legend to 1.